# Rescale thumbnails on window resize

Tags: jquery

I have a list of inline thumbnails, all uniform height but differing widths. They simply "float left".

I want them all to scale up/down depending on the window size, kinda like this site: http://davidellis.co.uk

Is this an existing jQuery plugin? The JS source on that site looks compressed or something, I can't make sense of it.

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQueryUI resize.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#synchronous-resize

just have to select all of the children in the alsoResize option.

there may be plugins that are even more specific to what you are doing however.